# Importing a css file (CDN vs Local)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

There's something strange about this.

If I use:

```
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

All works fine. But If I download it (i need to download to work offline) and then use (**yes, the path is correct**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/css/lib/font_awesome/all.css">
```

I get

> fa-solid-900.woff2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with
>   a status of 404 (Not  (Not Found) fa-solid-900.woff Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   fa-solid-900.ttf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
>   status of 404 (Not Found)

**Why the cdn doesn't give me any error and the other does?**

Web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.woff2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.woff</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ttf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: hm... I see the css is fetching `url(../webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2)`. how do I fix this for local usage?

Comment: Do you have the fonts folder at the same directory level as the css file?

Comment: where is the fonts folder?

Comment: Actually it's not on the same level. But the fonts will come within the download (at least it should)

Answer (score 4):

This is simply because the stylesheet uses relative paths to the fonts. You didn't download those fonts, just the stylesheet. Hence the fonts are not found on your system.

If you need the absolute font-face rules, here they are:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:Font Awesome\ 5 Brands;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    src:url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot);
    src:url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2) format("woff2"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff) format("woff"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf) format("truetype"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")
}
@font-face{
    font-family:Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    src:url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot);
    src:url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2) format("woff2"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff) format("woff"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf) format("truetype"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")
}
@font-face{
    font-family:Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:900;
    src:url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot);
    src:url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2) format("woff2"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff) format("woff"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf) format("truetype"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fontawesome 5 is best used via the JS version - it give many many more options...

https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js

Or you can download the whole package and link to the relevant js file.

Comment: Yes there you go.. this is the simplest way to use font awesome offline I was struggling with this using angular but it works great. here is an updated link https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/js/all.js